# Macro - Copy and Paste Cells Every Other Row

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple rows of data, where I'm trying to make another row and take Column F into the new Column D line by line.  I have the create new row macro set up, but how can I have a loop that would copy a cell from F into the new row in D?

Basically like:

```
Range("F3").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("D4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

For every other row.

So like the next one would put "F5" into "D6", and continue this till the end of the sheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `For` loop, with `Step 2` to skip two cells:

```
Sub copyMove()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To lastRow Step 2
    Cells(i + 1, 4).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Cells(i, 6).Value = ""
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

(This assumes you just want the values. If you need a formula, then it needs slight tweaking so let me know).